# Empty span siblings become predecessors

Tags: xml, xslt

What would cause `<span></span><span></span><span></span>` to transform to `<span><span><span></span></span></span>`, but not transform `<span>a</span><span>a</span><span>a</span>`?

Comment: Could you show use the XSLT involved, and then we may be able to help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="span[not(node())]">
  <span>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::span[not(node())]]"/>
  </span>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following document** (the provided fragment, wrapped into a single top element -- to be made a well-formed XML document):

```
<p>
<span></span><span></span><span></span>
</p
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<p>
   <span>
      <span>
         <span/>
      </span>
   </span>
</p>
```

**Also, as required, if we apply the same transformation (above) to this XML document**:

```
<p>
 <span>a</span><span>a</span><span>a</span>
 <span></span><span></span><span></span>
</p>
```

**the result preserves "as-is" the `span` elements that have a child node**:

```
<p>
   <span>a</span>
   <span>a</span>
   <span>a</span>
   <span>
      <span>
         <span/>
      </span>
   </span>
</p>
```

**Explanation**:

1. We use the "fine-grained" identity rule, which copies every node "as-is" and does this only one node at a step.
2. There is a single template that overrides the fine-grained identity template for any `span` element that has no children nodes. It re-creates the element and processes the first sibling that is also an empty `span` element.